# How can we avoid to list the products under same category in first page using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working with an e-commerce platform and I am managing the product listing page. We have products group and multiple products under each group. We need to list all the products under each group. But I just want to avoid the product displaying together under the same group or I want to list the products under the same group in different pages.

Now I am managing pagination with Offset. I just tried with the order by newID(). But it's not for my criteria as it's not working all the scenario. What is the best solution for this?

```
SELECT   
    COUNT(1) OVER() AS TotalCount,
    MRP, OnlineSalesRate, ProductMasterTitle,
    ID, pk_intProductAutoId, UniqueName,
    ImagePath AS ProductImage ,
    CatalogueValues, ProductName, 
    decOfferPercentage AS Offerpercentage,
    vaStatus
FROM 
    Inventory.Products P WITH(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN 
    Inventory.ProductMaster PM WITH(NOLOCK) ON P.intProductMasterID = PM.ProductMasterID
INNER JOIN 
    master.ProductType PT WITH(NOLOCK) ON pm.ProductTypeID = pt.ProductTypeID
ORDER BY
    (CASE @SortType
        WHEN 'LH' THEN P.mnOnlineSalesRate
     END) ASC,
    (CASE @SortType 
        WHEN 'HL' THEN p.mnOnlineSalesRate
     END) DESC,
    (CASE @SortType
        WHEN 'AZ' THEN p.vaProductName
     END) ASC,
    (CASE @SortType 
        WHEN 'ZA' THEN p.vaProductName
     END) DESC
    --,(CASE @SortType 
    --when 'hl' then cm.OfferedPrice
    -- END) desc
    OFFSET @pagesize * (@pageno - 1) ROWS 
        FETCH NEXT @pagesize ROWS ONLY OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

[image]

Comment: Please post desired and received results.

Comment: `WITH(NOLOCK)` means `read dirty and duplicate data while taking extra locks`. It won't fix whatever performance problem you have

Comment: As for the query itself, it looks like you confused report pages with result paging. SQL queries (in any product) don't layout data. The result rows are just that -rows. There are no groups or pages. `OFFSET .. FETCH NEXT` knows nothing about the groups that produced those rows.

Comment: BTW there's no grouping in this query anyway, just results returned in the order specified by `@SortType`